# Show JSON content depending on user id iOS

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, json

I want to show the content depending on user id.
The user log-in to the App, after the successful login, he will see the content depending on his id that is retrieved from the JSON file which is connected the the external mysql database.

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>  [super viewDidLoad];
>  NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.example.com/page.php?user_id=1"];
>  NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
>  NSError *error = nil;
> NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
> NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);
> self.something = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"something"];
> }
> ```

**My problem is :**

How to make " **1** " in ( **user_id=1** ) dynamic, in a way, it will be changed automatically when the user log-in to his account.

Comment: Are you simply asking how to dynamically create the URL string?

Comment: Actually I am a newbie on iOS development, and I think my question was very clear according to what I am needing. So, if you can help me, you'll be save my time a lot ! Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Prepare URL dynamically

```
NSString *userID = @"23";//Get your userID after login
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.example.com/page.php?user_id=%@",userID];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `StringWithFormat` Method of NSString Class, This methods helps you in creating dynamic NSString Objects,

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString userId = @"your user id here";
    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"http://api.example.com/page.php?user_id=%@",userId]];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);
    self.something = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"something"];
   }
```